# How to get row counts on a dynamic table if <tr> numbers keep changing

Tags: html, selenium, automated-tests, ui-automation, dynamic-tables

As a tester, I need to verify the total number of rows on a dynamic table. I found that HTML only displays 22 `<tr>` at the maximum. I have 50 rows actually on the table, but when I run the following code on my automation, it only returns 22. The `<tr>` rows on HTML keep changing when I scroll down the rows on the table, but never have 50 rows. It makes my test fail.

```
int iRowsCount = driver.findElements(By.XPath("/html/body/app-root/div/***/div[1]/table/tbody/tr")).Count;
```

How can I get the correct count of rows?

HTML structure is like this,

```
<div class=****>
 <table ********>
   <thead *****>...</thead>
   <tbody *****>
     <tr ****>.... </tr>
     <tr ****>.... </tr>
     <tr ****>.... </tr>
     <tr ****>.... </tr>
     <tr ****>.... </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot ****>...</tfoot>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: I faced similar problem. In my case also rows are dynamic and maximum of 60 <tr> displays. And on scrolling, the new rows(<tr>) will be loaded. So I guess you also need use scrollInView javascript function to load the remaining rows. If it makes sense I can post an answer.

Comment: When I am scrolling, new rows are loaded but old rows disappeared. Is it same as yours? If you could post an answer it will be brilliant. Many thanks.

Comment: @Cissi I missed your comment. I can post an answer if you are still looking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code and let me know.

```
boolean element = scrollIntoListView("max", false, webElement);
     if(element == true){
      /*Perform actions on element*/
     }
```

Call the method `scrollIntoListView` wherever you want to scroll and look for the required element.

```
    /*
     * This method is to scroll into list for particular element
     * 
     * @Params - List number, true or false, webElement.
     * 
     * Example#1: The list is having 60 elements and if you want to scroll till last
     * element and you want that element to be displayed on bottom of page then the
     * parameters should be like this. scrollIntoListView(max, false, element)
     *
     * Example#2: The list is having 60 elements and if you want to scroll till 30th
     * element and you want that element to be displayed on top then the parameters
     * should be like this. scrollIntoListView(30, true, element)
     */

    public static boolean scrollIntoListView(String listNumber, boolean topOrBottom, WebElement element) {
        WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) Driver.driverMap.get("WEBDRIVER");

        /*Here waitForVisibilityOfWebElement method returns an element if it is visible on DOM else null value will be returned.*/
        WebElement element = waitForVisibilityOfWebElement("element");
        if (element != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            int tillElement = 0;
            List<WebElement> optionList = null;

            if (listNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("max")) {
                optionList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(
                        "xPath to list of elements"));
                tillElement = (optionList.size() - 1);
            } else {
                tillElement = Integer.valueOf(listNumber);
            }
            javascriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(" + topOrBottom + ");",
                    optionList.get(tillElement));

            /*Once you scroll down to the bottom or top of the element then again look for that element.*/
            element = waitForVisibilityOfWebElement("element");
            if (element != null) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Note**: You have to write your own `waitForVisibilityOfWebElement` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I need to return back the count for all the rows on the table rather than finding a particular row. Scrolling down to the bottom won't give me a solution as the top rows will disappear anyway during the scrolling.

Comment: @Cissi what is your exact case? Do you want get all the rows? or trying to perform actions on particular row? Please post the `HTML` code and elaborate the case.

Comment: I am testing a drop down list for a table. It is used to show how many results you want to see on the table. When I select 50 or 100 I should see there are 50 or 100 rows but I can never see that many as the screen only shows 22 rows at the maximum. HTML structure is pasted above.

Comment: In UI, you were able to see 22 rows at a time and when you scroll down remaining rows will be loaded. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi @Nandan A Yes. When I scroll down, the remaining rows will be loaded but meanwhile the existed row on the top will disappear.

Comment: @Cissi `<tr class="dx-row dx-data-row dx-column-lines" role="row" aria-level="2" aria-selected="false" aria-rowindex="60">` this the `<tr>` tag from from my application. And if you see the `rowindex` value as `60` and when I scroll down remaining `<tr's>` will be loaded. So I will scroll till bottom of the list and get the total rows based on `rowindex` value. So do you have any attributes in your html tags?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have <rowindex>, I only have <role> and <row-class> for each <tr>.

Comment: Can we do like this?
1. Get the available `<tr's>` using `findElements`. Lets say 22 are returned.
2. Scroll till last element and again get the available `<tr's>` using `findElements`. Lets say 15 returned.
3. If we sum both results, cannot we achieve what you need?

Comment: Sounds like a solution. I'll try it. Thanks, Nandan.

Comment: @Cissi Please let me know the outcome